# Foreach loop to get next page of links with BeautifulSoup/Mechanize/Python

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I have a **view**:

```
def Processinitialscan(request):
    EnteredDomain = request.GET.get('domainNm')

    #get raw output
    getDomainLinksFromGoo = settings.GOOGLE_BASEURL_FOR_HARVEST+settings.GOO_RESULT_DOMAIN_QUERIED+EnteredDomain
    rawGatheredGooOutput = mechanizeBrowser.open(getDomainLinksFromGoo)

    beautifulSoupObj = BeautifulSoup(mechanizeBrowser.response().read()) #read the raw response
    getFirstPageLinks = beautifulSoupObj.find_all('cite') #get first page of urls

    pattern = re.compile('^.*start=')   #set regex to search on - find anything like: " <domain and path here>start= "
    getRemainingPageUrls = beautifulSoupObj.find_all('a',attrs={'class': 'fl', 'href': pattern})

    NumberOfUrlsFound = len(getRemainingPageUrls)

    MaxUrlsToGather = ((NumberOfUrlsFound*10)+settings.GOOGLE_RESULT_AMT_ACCOUNT_FOR_PAGE_1) # +10 because 10 represents the urls on the first page

    url_data = UrlData(NumberOfUrlsFound, pattern) 
    #return HttpResponse(MaxUrlsToGather)

    return render(request, 'VA/scan/process_scan.html', {
        'url_data':url_data,'EnteredDomain':EnteredDomain,'getDomainLinksFromGoo':getDomainLinksFromGoo,
        'getRemainingPageUrls' : getRemainingPageUrls, 'NumberOfUrlsFound':NumberOfUrlsFound,
        'getFirstPageLinks' : getFirstPageLinks, 'MaxUrlsToGather' : MaxUrlsToGather
    })
```

and a **template**:

```
{% block block_containercontent %}
    {% autoescape on %}
    <h1>{{ EnteredDomain }}</h1>
<strong>url used: </strong>{{ getDomainLinksFromGoo }}<br />
<hr>
<br>
<strong>first page of links</strong> {{ getFirstPageLinks }}
<hr>
<br><strong>number of "next" links</strong> {{ NumberOfUrlsFound }}
<hr>
<br>
<strong>remaining urls:</strong> {{ getRemainingPageUrls }}
    {% if url_data.num_of_urls > 1 %}
    {% for url in url_data.url_list %}
        {{ url }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
    {% endautoescape %}

{% endblock block_containercontent %}
```

This template outputs:

```
url used: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aasite.com


first page of links [<cite>www.google.com/webmasters/</cite>, <cite>www.asite.com</cite>, <cite>www.asite.com/blog/</cite>, <cite>www.asite.com/blog/projects/</cite>, <cite>www.asite.com/blog/category/internet/</cite>, <cite>www.asite.com/blog/category/goals/</cite>, <cite>www.asite.com/blog/category/uncategorized/</cite>, <cite>www.asite.com/blog/why-i-left-facebook/2013/01/</cite>, <cite>www.asite.com/blog/category/startups-2/</cite>, <cite>www.asite.com/blog/category/goals/</cite>, <cite>www.asite.com/blog/category/internet/</cite>]


number of "next" links 2
```

My question: how do I utilize the `NumberOfUrlsFound` in a loop within the template to generate links like: `/search?q=site:entereddomain.com&start=10`, `/search?q=site:entereddomain.com&start=20`, then follow the links using beautifulsoup based on the value of NumberOfUrlsFound. So if NumberOfUrlsFound = 2, then urls `search?q=site:asite.com&start=10`, `search?q=site:asite.com&start=20` should be generated, furthermore:

(puesdo code..):

```
if(NumberOfUrlsFound > 1)
    foreach(NumberOfUrlsFound)
        # generate url with start=n+10  
        ## asite.com?/search?start=10  
        ## Then ...
        ## asite.com?/search?start=20
        ## and so on ..
        # where n represents the previous number
        # this n number is determined by `NumberOfUrlsFound` which might have a value of 2 for example
        # this value of 2 represents a max value of start=20 value to generate urls on.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can create a data object to represent the data you want to display in the template.

```
class UrlData(object):
    def __init__(self, num_of_urls, url_pattern):
        self.num_of_urls = num_of_urls
        self.url_pattern = url_pattern

    def url_list(self):
        # Returns a list of strings that represent the urls you want based on num_of_urls
        # e.g. asite.com/?search?start=10
        urls = []
        for i in xrange(self.num_of_urls):
            urls.append(self.url_pattern + 'start=' + str((i + 1) * 10))
        return urls
```

In your views.py

```
# Create a UrlData object from NumberOfUrlsFound and a url_pattern
# url_pattern being the asite.com/?search?start=
url_data = UrlData(NumberOfUrlsFound, getDomainLinksFromGoogle) 

return render(request, template, {'url_data': url_data, ...})
```

Just create object with the data in your view function and pass the object to the template.

In your template you can do something like:

```
# Mirroring your check
{% if url_data.num_of_urls > 1 %} 
    # We'll iterate through the url_list created from the function defined in UrlData
    {% for url in url_data.url_list %}
         {{ url }} # asite.com/?search...
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

In the template, when you call `url_data.url_list` it'll run the function in `UrlData`

Comment: Anyway you could add comments to this so I could follow it better ?

Comment: Is this helpful?  Do you have any further questions?  The general principal is to create a data object to do the work that you want to do in your psuedocode.

Comment: Where is class UrlData(object): going into? Views.py?

Comment: It could be added to `views.py`.  You could also create a new file such as `urldata.py` and add `from urldata import UrlData` to `views.py`.  It's a matter of preference.

Comment: url_pattern is undefined here?

Comment: nvm, I switched it to my patterns var. Please see my updated code above, it is not outputting anything...

Comment: url_pattern needs to be the string of the base url that you are appending 10, 20 etc.  it's not the regex pattern.  You are building a list of strings with url_list.  The expected output of url_list should be ['asite.com/search?start=10', '...'] or something.

Comment: Tim, my question is how are these urls generated? I'm trying to generate them from `(getDomainLinksFromGoogle)+start=n` . N representing the value of `NumberOfUrlsFound` which might be `2` for example. This '2' value represents `20`, so `getDomainLinksFromGoogle+start=10`, `getDomainLinksFromGoogle+start=20` would be generated. The value of pattern should be able to accept multiple strings. Does that make sense?

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect what I think you are trying to get at.  Pass getDomainLinksFromGoogle as the url_pattern.  If we look at what url_list is doing, it's a for loop from 0 to n-1 and building a string.  I don't know what your base_string would be, but that's what url_pattern is for (a string representing your base url).  I probably got you confused by using the word pattern and you having a variable called pattern.